# Error when trying to access variable inside a for loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've got some code below that loops through a XML document to grab certain information. I want to grab 3 bits of information and place them in variables. As the code shows i have declared the variables before the loop, then after the loop i try to use the variables it mentions that they are unassigned.

I also think having 3 loops probably isn't the best way to do this but couldn't find another way to get all three bits of information.

Heres the code;

```
private void findDetails(String school)
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load("proxies.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> proxydetails = from el in root.Elements("item") where (string)el.Element("schoolname") == school select el;

        String SchoolAddress1, Port, Enabled = "";

        foreach (XElement el in proxydetails)
        {
            SchoolAddress1 = (string)el.Element("schooladdress");          
        }
        foreach (XElement el in proxydetails)
        {
             Port = (string)el.Element("schoolport");

        }
        foreach (XElement el in proxydetails)
        {
             Enabled = (string)el.Element("schoolenabled");

        }

        MessageBox.Show(SchoolAddress1);
        }
```

I've just checked what data is returned in proxydetails and it is the following;

```
<item>
<schoolname>Primary School</schoolname>
<schooladdress>proxy</schooladdress> 
  <schoolport>80</schoolport> 
  <schoolenabled>1</schoolenabled> 
  </item>
```

Here is the updated code that now works;

```
private void findDetails(String school)
        {
            XElement root = XElement.Load("proxies.xml");

            IEnumerable<XElement> ProxyDetails = from el in root.Elements("item") where (string)el.Element("schoolname") == school select el;

            String schoolAddress1 = "";
            String port = "";
            String enabled = "";

            foreach (XElement el in ProxyDetails)
            {
                schoolAddress1 = (string)el.Element("schooladdress");
                port = (string)el.Element("schoolport");
                enabled = (string)el.Element("schoolenabled");
            }


             MessageBox.Show(schoolAddress1);
            }
```

Comment: are you sure proxydetails having data? + You actually do not require 3 loops!

Comment: Sounds like you are having nothing in the proxydetails and the loops do not occure at all. Run it in debug mode and tell us that is the item count in the enumerator before entering the first loop.

Comment: i've just added what was contained in proxydetails

Comment: 1. You are looping and assigning new values to the same variable repeatedly. Only the last value read will be remembered therefore. 2. You don't need three separate loops. 3. The variables are assigned on declaration, so where are you getting an error and what error is it? 4. If `proxydetails` is an empty list, the loops won't be run, so `SchoolAddress1` etc will all be "" still. 5. Please fix your casing: the method should use *PascalCase*, the variables should use `camelCase`. You are just making it hard for others to read you code by not following those conventions.

Comment: I'm getting the following error even before i run the app. Use of unassigned local variable 'SchoolAddress1' on the messagebox line near the bottom

Comment: Compiler is telling you that if proxydetails will be empty, `SchoolAddress1` will not have any value (because you declared it without initializing it), try declaring it like this `String SchoolAddress1 = "", Port = "", Enabled = "";`

Comment: var schooldetails = proxydetails.Select(x=> new { schoolAddress1 = x.schooladdress, Port = x.schoolport, Enabled = x.schoolenabled}); Then MessageBox.Show(schooldetails.schoolAddress1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
String SchoolAddress1, Port, Enabled = "";
```

is equivalent to:

```
String SchoolAddress1;
String Port;
String Enabled = "";
```

If you want to initialise them all, you need to it like:

```
String SchoolAddress1 = "";
String Port = "";
String Enabled = "";
```

As the compiler cannot know whether `proxydetails` will contain anything, it cannot know if `SchoolAddress1` will be assigned a value in the loop. So it plays safe and warns that the variable may be undefined at the point you try to read it.

Comment: this was the answer, I've also altered the naming conventions of variables and methods and also removed the redundant for loops. to help others i'll post the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
private void findDetails(string school)
    {
        var root = XElement.Load("proxies.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> proxydetails = from el in root.Elements("item") where (string)el.Element("schoolname") == school select el;

        var schoolAddress1 = string.empty;
        var port = string.empty;
        var enabled = string.empty;

        var result = proxydetails.Select(x => new { schoolAddress1 = x.schooladdress, port = x.schoolport, enabled = x.schoolenabled}).ToLost(); 

         MessageBox.Show(result[0].schoolAddress1);
        }
```

Because in your code "" was assigned only to Port;
+ follow code conventions for better programming.

Answer (score 0):

Init you string with string.Empty value:

```
String SchoolAddress1, Port, Enabled = "";
```

should be

```
String SchoolAddress1 = string.Empty, Port = string.Empty, Enabled = string.Empty;
```

Also, merge the foreach loops into one:

```
foreach (XElement el in proxydetails)
{
    SchoolAddress1 = (string)el.Element("schooladdress"); 
    Port = (string)el.Element("schoolport");    
    Enabled = (string)el.Element("schoolenabled");
}
```